# How to parse JSON alike structure in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parsing

On Linux(on Windows agent it runs ok) machine my script receives not a JSON, but something like this:

```
@{x=value1; y=value2; z=value3}
```

so `$parameters = ConvertFrom-Json $parameters` no longer works as this is not a JSON, but instead of `:` we have `=` and instead of `,` we have `;`. How to easily parse this in PowerShell?

---

It comes from Terraform. I do this:

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["Powershell.exe", "./testScript.ps1"]

  query = {
    foo = "${var.someString}"
    bar = "Hardcoded"
  }
}
```

but the parameters on LINUX look like above.

Comment: This looks like the raw syntax for a hashtable in PowerShell. In what context are you receiving this? In your real data, are there quotes around the values like `x="value1"`, `y="value2"` and so on? If there are no quotes, are they numeric values such as `int`s?

Comment: What command are you running to get this output?  This utility might have a flag to use to control the output format.

Comment: The real solution is to serialize the data as JSON from the source, but if OP can confirm the data structure there is an easy code solution to be had here... though I will warn against it.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Please see the edit, on Windows it works ok.

Comment: Looks like you can append this to most terraform commands to force export as JSON, does this work?  `output -json > ./someJson.json`

Comment: Phew, on a good note I don't have to mention an insecure coding solution here. On a bad note, I don't use terraform to get data from PS in this way so I'm not sure what the cause or solution is here. @FoxDeploy might be onto something though.

Comment: I would check this guide.  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#argument-reference  Also, try forcing the output type you want.  Update your script to export a JSON object instead of relying on passing it to the host.

Comment: You should paste your script into here, otherwise we have no way to know what this would do `so $parameters = ConvertFrom-Json $parameters`.  For instance, from your terraform command, we don't see those params being posted in